# API to detect whether the post shared in facebook is private or public using post id

Tags: php, android, facebook-graph-api, access-token

I'm showing the facebook embed in a native view.With the help of app Access Token and Graph API, I'm getting a JSON resposne , from which I'm setting the native view of the embed. I'm using a below Graph API request:

"https://graph.facebook.com/postId?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN".

But this returns a response only for the posts shared by public groups and public pages. For the posts shared by some user(private posts), it throws error. The error is as given below:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Requires user session",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "ALrl5/9gwN3"
   }
}
```

This is expected as we cannot get the details of the private posts. But recently, we received a mail from the FB team as:
      "In the last three hours 100% of the calls to the method GET status resulted in error".

We cannot avoid this error, as we won't be knowing whether it's a private or public post. We have the post ID. So, is it possible to know whether the post shared is private or public using the Post ID. If we come to know about the type of the post in the beginning, then we can avoid sending request to fetch private post details.

Thanks,

Sangeetha

Comment: I would put that question in a REPLY to the email you were sent by FaceBook

Comment: I have already posted it in the facebook forum...Posted here, just to know, if anyone else has also faced this issue.